# Cross browser and future proof method of extracting date from ISO 8601 format?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

We are using facebook's API to get some posts and their corresponding dates and display them on a website we've built. The facebook API would return the date in the following format:

`2016-05-22T10:38:38+0000`

Which I've identified to be the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Until recently, we used code similar to the following to extract a readable date in the mm/dd/yyyy format:

```
//created_time = '2016-05-22T10:38:38+0000'
var date = new Date(created_time).toLocaleDateString();
```

However we noticed that this doesn't work in iOS safari, and all the solutions include splitting the string and parsing it to the Date() function.

I thought that something simple and dirty like this should work:

```
var getDate = function(date) {
    var day   = date.substr(8, 2);
    var month = date.substr(5, 2);
    var year  = date.substr(0, 4);
    return [day, month, year].join('/');
}
```

But my colleague has reservations about its future proofness. What if Facebook decides to change the format in which its date is returned? Completely valid concern. So can anyone recommend a programmatic, cross browser method of returning a readable dd/mm/yyyy format date from that string? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't `Date.parse` the explicit way to parse iso 8601 in js? Have you tried that? Your co-worker's  reservations are valid, simply on the grounds that the full spectrum of iso 8601 is not captured in that `getDate` function.

Comment: @CrescentFresh—No. Neither *Date.parse* or the *Date* constructor should be used to parse date strings as they are not consistently or correctly implemented across browsers.

Comment: @RobG: thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the format of the string, you can't confidently parse it. You can guess the format and generate a date, but even if you end up with a valid date you still don't know if you parsed it correctly. You should be parsing the string manually anyway (a library can help, but if you only have one format, a simple function is sufficient).

The following will reliably parse an ISO 8601 extended format date and time string.

```js
/* Parse ISO date string in format yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sss+hh:mm or Z
**
** @param (string} s - string to parse in ISO 8601 extended format
**                     yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sss+/-hh:mm or z
**                     Ttime zone separator can be omitted,
**                       e.g. +05:30 or +0530
**                     Date and time separator "T" can be replaced by space
**                       e.g. 2016-04-23 12:00:00-0700
**                     Date only form (2016-04-30) is treated as local (per ISO 8601,
**                     but ECMA-262 requires as GMT (Z or 0 offset).
**
** @returns {Date}   - returns a Date object. If any value out of range,
**                     returns an invalid date.
*/
function parseISO(s) {
  // Create base Date object
  var date = new Date();
  // Object to return if invalid date
  var invalidDate = new Date(NaN);
  // Set some defaults
  var sign = -1, tzMins = 0;
  var tzHr, tzMin;
  // Trim leading and trailing whitespace
  s = s.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,'').toUpperCase();
  // Get parts of string and split into numbers
  var d  = (s.match(/^\d+(-\d+){0,2}/)             || [''])[0].split(/\D/);
  var t  = (s.match(/[\sT]\d+(:\d+){0,2}(\.\d+)?/) || [''])[0].split(/\D/);
  var tz = (s.match(/Z|[+\-]\d\d:?\d\d$/)          || [''])[0];

  // Resolve timezone to minutes, may be Z, +hh:mm or +hhmm
  // substr is old school but more compatible than slice
  // Don't need to split into parts but makes validation easier
  if (tz) {
    sign  = /^-/.test(tz)? 1 : -1;
    tzHr  = tz == 'Z'? 0 : tz.substr(1,2);
    tzMin = tz == 'Z'? 0 : tz.substr(tz.length - 2, 2)*1;
    tzMins = sign * (tzHr*60 + tzMin);
  }

  // Validation
  function isLeap(year){return year % 4 != 0 || year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0}
  // Check number of date parts and month is valid
  if (d.length > 3 || d[1] < 1 || d[1] > 12) return invalidDate;
  // Test day is valid
  var monthDays = [,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
  var monthMax = isLeap(d[0]) && d[1] == 2? 29 : monthDays[d[1]];
  if (d[2] < 1 || d[1] > monthMax) return invalidDate;
  // Test time parts
  if (t.length > 5 || t[1] > 23 || t[2] > 59 || t[3] > 59 || t[4] > 999) return invalidDate;
  // Test tz within bounds
  if (tzHr > 12 || tzMin > 59) return invalidDate;

  // If there's a timezone, use UTC methods, otherwise local
  var method = tz? 'UTC' : '';
  
  // Set date values
  date['set' + method + 'FullYear'](d[0], (d[1]? d[1]-1 : 0), d[2]||1);
  // Set time values - first member is '' from separator \s or T
  date['set' + method + 'Hours'](t[1] || 0, (+t[2]||0) + tzMins, t[3]||0, t[4]||0);

  return date;
}

['2016-04-12T04:31:56.200+05:30','2016-02-01','2016-01-01 17:51:12-0700','2016-01-01T17:51:12Z'].forEach(function (s) {
  var d = parseISO(s);
  document.write('String: ' + s + '<br>' +
                 'Local time: ' + d + '<br>' +
                 'toISOString: ' + d.toISOString() + '<br><br>'
                );
 });
```

The above can be reduced to much less code, it's intended to be easy to read and maintain and more code doesn't necessarily mean it's slower than a shorter version (though caching the regular expressions would help if performance is an issue).