# Parse OffsetDateTime in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

How can I parse string "1890-09-30T23:59:59+01:16:20" in JavaScript?

The string returned by Java server `offsetDateTime.format(ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)`

**Test**: 
new Date('1890-09-30T23:59:59+01:16:20') => Invalid Date

**More info about this strange datetime**: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/hungary/budapest?year=1890

**Note**: Angular 2's date pipe fails too.

Comment: new Date() fails for the local time reference of `+01:16:20` at the end. If you slice off the end, parse `1890-09-30T23:59:59` and then add the `01:16:20` to it again, you'll get the correct date.

Comment: That is a weird offset. What time zone does it represent? There's an answer to [*Cross browser and future proof method of extracting date from ISO 8601 format*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662898/cross-browser-and-future-proof-method-of-extracting-date-from-iso-8601-format/37670025#37670025) to parse ISO format strings with an offset, though it only expects the offset in minutes. It would be simple to modify it to accommodate an offset with seconds.

Comment: I don't agree that the "duplicate" is a duplicate. The answers aren't focussed on parsing and don't address the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea:

'1890-09-30T23:59:59+01:16:20'.split(/[-,:,T,+]+/);

This will return an array of your numerical values.

[ '1890',
  '09',
  '30',
  '23',
  '59',
  '59',
  '01',
  '16',
  '20' ]

Comment: The parsed result should be equal with
new Date("1890-09-30T23:43:39+01:00") or new Date("1890-09-30T22:43:39Z")